# Binary Arithmetic Coding and Arithmetic Coding Difference

Tags: encoding, compression, decoding

What is the difference binary arithmetic coding and arithmetic coding?

I don't understand these two notions. I think, these algorithms are same. Can you give details and examples for these notions and difference?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should link the source or sources of what you're trying to compare, so we can see what exactly they're talking about.

However I can guess that binary arithmetic coding is specifically referring to encoding a 0 or 1 at each step, i.e. two symbols. You can also have q-ary arithmetic coding, where you split the probability into *q* intervals at each step, instead of two intervals at each step.

Comment: I try to understand these algorithms math. These algorithms using 1 and 0s. What is the difference? I think they are same.

Comment: I still see no links or references to what led to your question.